# How do I upload an image by passing the parameters in the URL using Swift?

Tags: swift, image-uploading, nsurlsession, nsurl

I am trying to upload an image by passing the parameters in the URL.But I am geting the response as "**The requested URL was not found on this server** " .

```
func uploadImage()
   {
     let imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)
     if(imagedata == nil ) { return }
     self.upLoadButton.enabled = false
     let parameter = ["**":"**"]
     let url = "***URL***"
     let uploadScriptUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(url)\(parameter)")
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uploadScriptUrl)
     request.setValue("Keep-Alive",forHTTPHeaderField: "connection")

     let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
     let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

     let task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: imagedata!)
     task.resume()
   }
```

Is there any procedure to upload the image? If yes , help me to recover my issue.

Comment: I think some server issue.

Comment: I think you are trying to hit a get request. If so then your parameter should be send as yourURL?imageNameParameter=imageData

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick list of things I see wrong:

- You're sending a `GET` request with a body.  You need to override the request type to send a `POST` request.
- You need to specify the `Content-Type` header on the request object.
- You need an actual piece of software on the server that knows how to take the files and store them somewhere.
- Your request URL needs to be the URL of that software on the server, **not** a local file URL.
- If you already have such a script, then you're using the wrong method to create the URL.  You should be using `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..." relativeToURL: nil]`.